# How to split props string in React?

Tags: reactjs, split

I have My React functional components accepting props string x which gives me 'props.x.split is not a function' error. But when I override props with exactly same string I don't have any errors, see below:

```
function My(props) {  
    console.log(typeof props.x, props.x); //string 41.9980,-71.4941      
    const loc = '41.9980,-71.4941'; //overriding arguments
    console.log(typeof loc, loc); //string 41.9980,-71.4941
    const lat = loc.split(",")[0].toString(); 
    const lon = loc.split(",")[1].toString();    
    return <h6>{lat,lon}</h6>;  //41.9980,-71.4941
}
```

But this one is not working:

```
function My(props) {  
    console.log(typeof props.x, props.x); //string 41.9980,-71.4941  
    const loc = props.x     
    const lat = loc.split(",")[0].toString(); // Uncaught TypeError: loc.split is not a function 
    const lon = loc.split(",")[1].toString();    
    return <h6>{lat,lot}</h6>;
}
```

**Update**: Main component where My function component is used

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      location: []     
    }; 
  }
  getLoc() {
    axios.get('http://ipinfo.io')
      .then((res) => {      
        this.setState({location:res.data.loc});        
      })                
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    this.getLoc();     

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >          
            <My x={this.state.location}/>                                       
      </div> 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible. There is something interfering you are not showing here. So this question is not answerable in this form. Or maybe at some point `props.x` is indeed `undefined` or something. Just log it and see how many time you get into `My` component.

Comment: Might need more of your code for context-- if I take your "not working" code and just try calling it with a fake `props` object it works fine (except that you misspelled `lon` as `lot` in your return markup).  Can you create a snippet that recreates the issue?